# Derive RegExp from set of strings

Tags: c++, regex, string

Imagine there is an arbitrary set of strings. We now suppose that they are all equal beside a few succeeding characters (if this assumption does not hold I'm fine with returning an error). I now want to derive a regular expression to identify the portion of the strings that is different.

```
Input:
"Hello Alice, I'm Bob.", "Hello John, I'm Bob.", "Hello Josh, I'm Bob."

Output:
"Hello (.+), I'm Bob."

Input:
"Monday", "Tree", "Dog"

Output:
Error
```

Maybe finding the [longest common substrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) or the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) could help? I'm not sure yet if one of them really applies to my problem or how to use them to solve it.

Comment: Since this is homework, I'll try to give a more "thoughtful" hint. I am not sure what your background in basic computation theory is, but it is often helpful to imagine questions like these as DFA's (or, probably in this case, an NFA which is equivalent). Try to create a state-diagram which yields the correct result and convert that to regular expression.

Comment: Dont know why this was tagged as homework. It is not! Anyway...I can't yet see how this is related to automata could you please explain in a bit more detail? I also do not see why my examples do not match my questions. If you could show me what you mean I will try to improve my question.

Comment: There are several algorithms for [induction of regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_of_regular_languages) that can generate a regular expression to match a set of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a problem and decided to use regexp to solve it -- now you have two problems. :-)

All kidding aside, you can break this down into two steps:

1. Identify differences between strings.
2. Look at all the differences and figure out a regexp to match them.

For (1), it's a matter of using a diff-computing library in your language (like `difflib` in Python) to find a list of identical regions between two strings. If all strings have common segments, then compare string-1 to each of string-[2..N] to analyze the resulting identical blocks (you have to be smart about comparing both the contents of each block and its position relative to other identical blocks). Extract and record text between the identical blocks too.

For your example, you'd get two identical block every time you compare: `"Hello "` and `", I'm Bob."`. 
The text between the identical blocks will be these strings: `"Alice"`, `"John"`, `"Josh"`.

For (2), the most trivial solution is to combine your findings into a quite literal regexp composed of:

`Hello` + `(Alice|John|Josh)` + `, I'm Bob.`

Or, replace any segment between the same identical blocks found in *all* strings with `.*`. Consider making that a non-greedy match -- `.*?`.

I don't know automata theory and can't help you with DFA/NFA, but that's a solid direction to go if you needed more precision.